# MongoDB advanced $lookup Query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to join two collections and get data.I know that this can be achieved by using $lookup, but the case is 'from' field in $lookup should have a dynamic value as explained below.

There are three collections in my db : inclusions,packages,page_content

[image]

I think you got what I meant..If there is any one who can help with this appreciate if..

Comment: Hi SNT93; I think your question would be better if, instead of posting a large image, you pasted your json and code into the question. It is useful having the red marks to indicate which data items should be joined - but you could do this just as well with an explanation in clear english, and that would make the question more searchable and findable - so more useful overall.

Comment: OKay thanx for the advice..

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic lookup is not possible as of now (v4.0)